# Authentication using Google API v3 OAuth 2.0 for Blogger API using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, blogger, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm working on an Web application to post blogs to blogger.com. I referenced Blogger API v3 client library and Google Oauth 2.0 to my project. Also created Credentials on Google Console. 
Now i have Client ID,Client secret and API Key. I have given Redirect URIs as http://Localhost and http://localhost:52892.
I'm using .JSON file.

My code is Here:

```
     using (var stream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/client_secret.json"), FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read))
     {
            //string credPath =   System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            string credPath = Server.MapPath("~/Credentials");
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials");
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                                                                    Scopes,
                                                                    "user",
                                                                    CancellationToken.None,
                                                                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            lblBlogTitle.Text = "Credential File Saved to :"+credPath;                
        }

        // Create Blogger API service.

        var service = new BloggerService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });

        // Define parameters of request.            

        // get blog by ID
        BlogsResource.GetRequest blogByID = service.Blogs.Get("BlogID");

        // List blog by name.
        //IList<Google.Apis.Blogger.v3.Data.Blog> blogs = 

        string blogName = blogByID.Execute().Name;
        lblNoti.Text = blogName;
```

Can some please tell me where i'm missing? I'm new to DotNet. Code level answer with a description will be very helpful for me.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the code you have?

Comment: Everytime I'm running the application. It takes a random port number in Redirect URI like Localhost:54456, next time it's taking localhost:54921 like this. So everytime in the Oauth it's taking Different URI from the specified one(localhost:52892.

Comment: try and set the redirect uri to http://localhost/authorize/

Comment: Where to set this Redirect URI. On Google Console? I tried it by setting it on Google console but same issue persists!

Comment: Yes in the Google developer console.

Comment: If that doesn't work then you either create one of type other while you are developing.   http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-oauth2/#Type_other   There is a way to fix visual studio but I haven't had time to write up how to do that yet.